# Age verification for Magento

Tags: php, javascript, css, html

this is an age verification for homepage.

```
<script language="javascript">


var agePrompt=prompt("What is your age?");

if (agePrompt>=18) alert('Welcome!')
else {
alert('Sorry! Come back in a few years!')
document.location=" ";//link if not 18

}
</script>
```

how can i do this for spesial categories?

Comment: 1) Javascript is easily defeated. You will need to have server-side code that does this. 2) There is a lot of work involved in this - you can look for an extension or start development yourself and we can help you with smaller questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to save the content to a javascript file (age-verification.js).

Then go to Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Categories -> {Select your category} -> Custo Design -> Custom Layout Update

Add

```
<reference name="head">
     <action method="addItem">
          <type>skin_js</type>
          <name>js/age-verification.js</name>
     </action>  
</reference>
```

See http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2013/10/24/adding-javascript-and-css-files-to-head-section-of-magento.html

**Also note you should be doing this server side, using php and session**

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the custom layout update field in the category's custom layout tab.

Enter the layout update to add your Javascript file for this specific category only.

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>your_js_file</script></action>
    <action method="addCss">
        <name>your_css_file</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```

the js file is sought in the /js folder, the css file in the templates skin folder